# How to encode code point list into UTF8 chunk using libICU?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, icu

Due to program requirements (fast access to individual characters), I am using `uint32_t[]` for characters. Simply stores *code points*, not UTF-32 *code units*. because I don't think UTF-32 code-unit and Unicode code-point is same thing, so I have to keep them separated.

The code points are taken from [`next32PostInc` function](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1ForwardCharacterIterator.html#acccb6c5e433ff1cbaa5830130b569e97)

And I need to encode these code-points into UTF-8 chunk using `libICU`, and it's hard to find character level accumulative encoder. I see a way by using [`UnicodeString::append()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a63a20b07358283970202766775a36adc), but it needs double conversions. [`ucnv_convert`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html#a2bdb6b1d3ac4069808348eb6961ce63d) functions seems to do the job, but only with UTF-32 *code units*. And I really am not sure about safety if I use them with *code points*. Currently I am looking for something inverse of `next32PostInc` function. How can I do that? If my idea on code-point and code-units, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Current Unicode spec defines UTF-32 code unit is equal to code point.

From the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html):

> Given that any industrial-strength text and internationalization
>   support API has to be able to handle sequences of characters, it makes
>   little difference whether the string is internally represented by a
>   sequence of UTF-16 code units, or by a sequence of **code-points ( = UTF-32 code units)**. Both UTF-16 and UTF-8 are designed to make working
>   with substrings easy, by the fact that the sequence of code units for
>   a given code point is unique.

So just use UTF-32 functions.